# Linux shell for Windows can't "see" files on a NAS

Tags: linux, windows-10, ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, linux-terminal

I have a NAS and I'm trying to open a Linux shell on a folder in this NAS, but when I right-click a folder (holding shift) and open the Linux shell it doesn't show the files there, It doesn't even show the folder, it opens as if I opened it clicking on the Ubuntu app instead of right-clicking a folder (It opens in the root).

On my Mac, I can use the terminal to interact with the files on the NAS, but from Windows, I cant make the Linux shell work there, how can I make the Linux shell open in my NAS folder, what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you open a Linux shell elsewhere (e.g., on a local folder)?

Comment: Yes, @singalongconflict, normally